# Data Factory with Azure Function calling completed stage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I would like to know if you have an azure function at the end of a data factory pipeline. Is the data factory said to be completed when it triggers the Azure Function or Data factory is completed when the triggered Azure function has been completed.

I am asking this, because I have large set of data which is going to be processed in Azure Function but there is few parameters which are coming from previous stages of ADF pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on how you are calling the function and what that function is doing.  It is possible to have Data Factory wait until the Function 'finishes' or more specifically returns a response to the web request that called it and it is also possible to just fire off a call from Data Factory and have the Pipeline plow on regardless of what the Function is doing.

---

That aside, I would question your use of Azure Functions to actually process "a large set of data" and would advise that (if you are not already) you use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) to trigger a seperate and better suited data processing tool and then wait for completion of the external process in an efficient manner, to save the compute costs that come with a long running standard Azure Function.

Comment: "it is also possible to just fire off a call from Data Factory and have the Pipeline plow on regardless of what the Function is doing." - How do you do this ? is there some settings to be enabled? I am calling my http triggered function which is going to do some transformation on data points in my database. so you are saying I can call my Data factory to be completed while the transformation is completed by Azure Function

Comment: One way this can be done is by triggering your Function within it's own Pipeline, with a very short timeout setting on the Function call.  Whilst this Pipeline will fail due to the timeout being hit, the main Pipeline can be set to not Wait on Completion so it will succeed.  This is not very elegant though.

Comment: The better option is to use the Durable Functions I mentioned.  They return an acknowledgement that they were successfully triggered and then should you want to, you can poll them to see how they are getting on.  If the process is still on-going it will return that status.  If it is finished, it will return the result as configured.  If you have a Durable Function that starts your final process, you can call it, receive an immediate acknowledgement response and finish your ADF pipeline without checking the status of the job you just started.